# Obj-C: Swipe to delete locking app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm having an issue with swipe to delete in UITableViews when using ECSlidingViewController.

I have a very simple example here: https://github.com/RichardSimko/ECSlidingViewControllerTest

The problem arises when you swipe to delete on the table cells, if you then try to open the menu using the menu button, which calls the method `[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];`, the app will lock up. However, if you use the swipe gesture to trigger the menu it won't.

As I'm not that familiar with animations and the likes I was wondering if anyone have any ideas as to what I can do to fix the issue in ECSlidingViewController. Or am I perhaps using it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be related to an issue with `ECSlidingViewController`. I fixed it in a PR, it was related to the recognizer setting `isInteractive` even when the view controller could not slide in the specified direction. More details in the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/issues/254